# Python Memory Error for a capitalize function

Tags: python

I am new to python and want to write a function that takes in a string and returns a list of all possible capitalizations of the string. here it is:

```
def transform_capitalize(st):
    l=[]
    l.append(st.lower())
    newl=l
    length=len(st)
    for x in range(0,length):
        for i in l:
            newl.append(i[:x]+i[x].upper()+i[(x+1):])
        l=newl
    return l
```

The logic is as follows:

Take the string and convert to lower cast then put into a list
then have a loop within a loop get the possibilities of each letter being uppercase one at a time and update the list after each letter position.

So for `Foo` as an example
`l=['foo']` and length is 3 so from 0 to 2 take every element in the list and capitalize the letter in the ith position, append these to the `newl`, then update the list after all capitalizations at that position have been made
so when `i` = 0 the list should be `["foo","Foo"]` at the end.

For `i` = 1 it should be `["foo","Foo""fOo","FOo"]` and for 2 it should be `['foo', 'Foo', 'fOo', 'FOo', 'foO', 'FoO', 'fOO', 'FOO']`.  The order doesn't matter, but more some reason I'm getting a memory error so I'm assuming its some infinite loop.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: lists are copied by reference, not by value. By appending elements from l to newl you are appending elements to itself, until the memory is filled. To make a copy do newl = l[:]

Answer (score 4):

These 2 lines are the problem:

```
newl=l
l = newl
```

When you assign a variable an array, the default behavior is for the variable to act as a *reference*, not a copy. It means, if you assign `a` an empty list , then you assign `a` to `b`, appending anything to `b` or `a` is one and same.

```
a = []
b = a
b.append("hello")
print(a) # prints ["hello"]
```

To copy an array in python, you use slicing:

```
a = []
b = a[:] #here
b.append("hello")
print(a) # prints []
```

Now, changing reference assignment to copying when intended:

```
def transform_capitalize(st):
    l=[]
    l.append(st.lower())
    newl=l[:]
    length=len(st)
    for x in range(0,length):
        for i in l:
            newl.append(i[:x]+i[x].upper()+i[(x+1):])
        l=newl[:]
    return l
transform_capitalize("hello"); #['hello', 'Hello', 'hEllo', 'HEllo', 'heLlo', 'HeLlo', 'hELlo', 'HELlo', 'helLo', 'HelLo', 'hElLo', 'HElLo', 'heLLo', 'HeLLo', 'hELLo', 'HELLo', 'hellO', 'HellO', 'hEllO', 'HEllO', 'heLlO', 'HeLlO', 'hELlO', 'HELlO', 'helLO', 'HelLO', 'hElLO', 'HElLO', 'heLLO', 'HeLLO', 'hELLO', 'HELLO']
```

Comment: gotcha thanks for that, wasnt sure how copying worked in python if its reference or copy.  Wont do that again thanks

Comment: you could remove lines 4 and 9 and simply do `for i in list(l)` and `l.append(…)`

Comment: @hop yes, but this advice should go to Anatoliy. I wanted to show how his function can be fixed and intended to have as less changes to his code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution could also be used:

```
def transform_capitalize(st):
  result = []
  if len(st) > 0:
     head = st[0]
     tails = transform_capitalize(st[1:])
     for t in tails:
       result.append( head.lower() + t )
       result.append( head.upper() + t )
  else:
    result = [ '' ]
  return result
```

Given an empty string, it will return a single empty string.  It could be modified if this is not what we want (by placing the stop condition at length 1 instead of 0).

Answer (score 0):

I'm bored, so here is a "Batteries Included" version of your function:

```
from itertools import product
from string import upper, lower

def capitalize(word):
    word = word.lower()
    for p in product([upper, lower], repeat=len(word)):
        yield ''.join(fn(letter) for fn, letter in zip(p, word))

if __name__=='__main__':
    print list(capitalize('foo'))
```